# Como pasar dos array como argumento a una funcion y que un for los navegue y haga un append segun la posición del segundo array

Tags: javascript, html

A ver si puedo explicar-me bien.
El objetivo es acortar un código que ya funciona. La información original son tres arrays de objeto

```
let listDemo = [];
let listRep = [];
let listIndp = [];
```

Por cada array tengo una función como la siguiente que me hace un append en una tabla y luego tengo una 4a función que lo hace sobre un total de los tres arrays.

```
function votedPartyDemo(array) {
    var total = 0;

    array.forEach((element) => {
      total = total + element.votes_with_party_pct;
    });
    var newData = document.createElement("td");
    newData.className = "text-center";
    newData.innerHTML = (total / 105).toFixed(2) + "%";
    rowDem.append(newData);
  }
  votedPartyDemo(listDemo);
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer pero no consigo es hacer una función con un loop que me lo haga todo. El problema llega a la hora de hacer el append en la tabla, porque tengo que hacer cada append en una `tr` que ya existe de antes.
Lo único que se me ha ocurrido es hacer otro array que almacene las tres variables que me hacen el `getElementById` .
De esta manera tendría lo siguiente:

```
let listDemo = [];
let listRep = [];
let listIndp = [];

let rowDem = document.getElementById("attGlanceDem");
let rowRep = document.getElementById("attGlanceRep");
let rowIndp = document.getElementById("attGlanceIndp");

let globalStoreA = [rowDem, rowRep, rowIndp];
let globalStoreB = [listDemo, listRep, listIndp];
```

Cómo le paso a una función los dos argumentos para que un `for` navegue los dos arrays y me haga el `append` según la posición de `i` en el loop?
Soy un poco novato en Js así que si me estoy metiendo en un berenjenal muy grande me lo podeis decir xD

Answer (score 0):

Al final he conseguido un resultado con el estoy contento

```js
function votedParty(innArray1, innArray2) {
    var totalParty = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (let i = 0, len = innArray2.length; i < len; i++) {
      let total = 0;
      for (let j = 0, llar = innArray2[i].length; j < llar; j++)
        total = total + innArray2[i][j].votes_with_party_pct;
      var newData = document.createElement("td");
      newData.className = "text-center";
      newData.innerHTML = (total / 105).toFixed(2) + "%";
      innArray1[i].append(newData);
      totalParty = totalParty + total;
    }
    newData = document.createElement("td");
    newData.className = "text-center";
    newData.innerHTML = (totalParty / 105).toFixed(2) + "%";
    rowTotal.append(newData);
  }
  votedParty(globalStoreA, globalStoreB);
```

No costaría mucho pasar esto a un forEach, pero de momento me aclaro mejor con un for completo